# How Ctrl-C propagates through tmux

Tags: linux, tmux

I know that when I hit Ctrl-C, the operating system pts system interprets it and sends a `SIGINT` to the foreground process group. I just wonder how it propagates through `tmux`.

Say I am running a normal Linux with an X server and window manager. I opened an `xterm` and in it a `zsh` running `tmux`. In this `tmux` I am running a `bash` and in it a `./a.out`.

Process tree like `window manager` -> `xterm` -> `zsh` -> `tmux client`. Then `tmux server` -> `bash` -> `./a.out`.

So when I hit Ctrl-C on my keyboard, X server first catches it and tells the active window `xterm` "hey this guy just hit Ctrl-C". `xterm` tells the process it's directly running (`zsh`) that I hit Ctrl-C by sending into the pseudo terminal `pts/0` a "Ctrl-C" character. The operating system saw a "Ctrl-C" character in a pseudo terminal and translates it to a `SIGINT` to the foreground process group (which is the `zsh` and `tmux client`). Then `tmux client` must have received this `SIGINT` so it tells `tmux server` and `tmux server` then sends `SIGINT` to the foreground process group of the pseudo terminal it just created (with `bash` and `./a.out` in it). Sorry if it all looks confusing. But because of how `tmux` works, `tmux server` and `tmux client` are two separate processes.

Now if I want to mimic this behavior, I could just send a `SIGINT` to `tmux client` and expect `./a.out` to receive a `SIGINT` as if I just pressed "Ctrl-C" on my keyboard. But nothing happens. I guess I am wrong somewhere and can you help me with it?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Send a signal to a running process?

Answer (score 0):

When sending `Ctrl-C` through `tmux`, there is never a signal involved on the client side.
`tmux client` sets `pts/0` to the so called raw mode. In this mode
`Ctrl-C` will not cause the kernel to send a signal, but simply passed through as a character. The keystroke is then forwarded to the `tmux server`. The server is running a pseudo terminal of its own, say `pts/1`, where Ctrl-C will cause a signal to be send.

Hence sending `SIGINT` to `tmux client` has a different effect than pressing `Ctrl-C` in the terminal where `tmux client` is running.

Setting the pts to raw mode can be found in the tmux sourcecode in [client.c](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/5ce34add77fa3517a01e63b915c5f4e3241af470/client.c#L353). The interesting functions are `cfmakeraw` and `tcsetattr`, see `man 3 termios` for more information.

(This is similar to what happens when sending Ctrl-C through an interactive ssh session, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161878)).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).